# Object references not being recognized

Tags: java, swing

```
private GameController gc = new GameController();

private boolean timerstart = false;

private JButton bhit = new JButton("HIT");

private JButton bstand = new JButton("STAND");

private JButton bdd = new JButton("DOUBLE DOWN");

// private JButton bsplit = new JButton("SPLIT")

private JButton 5chips = new JButton("5");
private JButton 10chips = new JButton("10");
private JButton 25chips = new JButton("25");
private JButton 100chips = new JButton("100");

private JTextArea tap = new JTextArea(5,5);

private JTextArea tad = new JTextArea(5,5);

private JTextArea tac = new JTextArea("Welcome to BlackJack Simulator!",1,5);

private Container cp = getContentPane();
// create the panel containing panels
private JPanel mainchippanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
// create the panel to contain the buttons
private JPanel chipandta = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

private JPanel chipbuttons = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

private JPanel playeroptions = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

private JPanel optnsandta = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

private JPanel mainoptnpanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

private JPanel handdisplays = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

private JPanel main1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

private JPanel main2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```

I'm making an applet, and for some reason only the code from gc to bdd is being recognized, as in it's as if all the code from the JButton for 5chips and onwards isn't even there.

I know this because the Class View isn't showing the references for the code past bdd, and the output keeps giving " expected" errors for each reference to the objects past bdd.

I have no clue why this is happening, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the exception are you getting?..post in the question..and post the full class code..

Comment: So, the code doesn't compile, is that what your problem is? If so, what is the exact and complete error message you get from the compiler? Which line does it refer to?

Comment: Not recognized? Leave the class view alone and please post the actual exceptions (not eclipse messages) and the errors the compiler gives you. Clean your project and rebuild it, see if it goes away.

Comment: Turns out the problem was the variable names for the chips. Sorry for the stupid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Cannot start with a variable name with a digit.
Change to:

```
private JButton chips5 = new JButton("5");
private JButton chips10 = new JButton("10");
private JButton chips25 = new JButton("25");
private JButton chips100 = new JButton("100");
```

Comment: ohhh yeah I forgot all about that. Thanks a lot!